# Почему не работает цикл for

Tags: javascript, html, css

На странице есть группа radioButton кнопок, которые разделены между собой при помощи атрибута name. Необходимо получить все эти кнопки и в цикле реагировать на нажатия по ним. Начал с того, что пытаюсь получить все элементы из этих групп. Объединил их в массив (предварительно получив HTML коллекцию), обхожу элементы в цикле и пытаюсь удостовериться, что могу получить к ним в цикле доступ. Но ни этот вариант, ни аналогичный вариант через foreach() не работают никак.

```js
function getRadioEl() {
  var radioButtСollection = document.getElementsByClassName("markNews");
  // получаю html коллекцию, в ней 18 элементов
  var radioButtArray = Array.from(radioButtСollection);
  //привожу коллекцию  к массиву

  for (var i = 0; i > radioButtArray.length; i++) {
    if (radioButtArray[i].checked === false) {
      console.log('false for ' + radioButtArray[i]);
    } else {
      console.log('true for ' + radioButtArray[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.ThisDay-default-index {
  position: relative;
}

.control-group .group-header:not(:nth-child(1)) {
  display: none;
}

.horizontal-scroll-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.control-group {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  max-width: 285px;
  max-height: 345px;
  min-height: 345px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
}

.thisday-container {
  width: 55%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.control {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.control input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.control__indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 4px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
}

.control-views-count {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font: normal normal normal 13px/1 FontAwesome;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #695454;
}

.control-views-count:before {
  margin: 4px;
}

.thisday-butt,
.thisday-btn {
  float: right;
}

.thisday-time {
  display: flex;
}

.thisday-content {
  clear: both;
}

.control-group .group-header:not(:nth-child(1)) h3 {
  display: none !important;
}

.control-button__container {
  text-align: center;
}

.thisday-list__button {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.group-header {
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.thisday-time #userdate {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

.bs-native-danger {
  color: #a94442;
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #ebccd1;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.thisday-form-butt {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.markNews {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

.markNews+.markNews_label__custom {
  background: #dad7d7;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.markNews:checked+.markNews_label__custom::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  background-color: #58b790;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.markNews_label__custom:hover {
  background: #cfe330;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.markNews-label {
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.label-checked {
  background-color: #72f1638f;
}

.control-group__label:not(.label-checked):hover,
.control-group__label:not(.label-checked):focus {
  background-color: #9dd9f68f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thisday-container">
  <span>Вы можете выбрать еще <strong id="countRadioButt"></strong> новостей</span>
  <div class="horizontal-scroll-wrapper">
    <div class="control-group">
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612539" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612539" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612539" 
    class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">13556                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612210" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612210" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612210" 
   class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">11376                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label label-checked">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612573" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612573" checked="checked" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612573" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">7523                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612378" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612378" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612378" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст</span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">7340                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612349" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612349" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612349" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">7068                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612405" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612405" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612405" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">5811                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612577" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612577" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612577" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">4354                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612478" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612478" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612478" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст</span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">4309                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612586" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612586" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612586" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">3887                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612443" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612443" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612443" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст</span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">3641                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612550" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612550" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612550" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст</span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">3404                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612479" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612479" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612479" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">3241                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612421" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612421" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612421" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">3196                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612466" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612466" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612466" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст</span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">3081                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612380" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612380" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612380" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">2901                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>

    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <h3 class="group-header">2016</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-523521" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2016][]" value=" 523521" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-523521" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текстм </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">3146                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2016</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-523515" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2016][]" value=" 523515" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-523515" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">2766                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2016</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label label-checked">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-523477" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2016][]" value=" 523477" checked="checked" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-523477" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">1825                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Я не получаю никаких сообщений об ошибке в консоль, не срабатывает console.log, ничего.

Как мне починить это все и заставить работать корректно? Корректно - в данном случае, чтобы я получил запись в console log результат для каждого элемента, который был затронут циклом for().

Comment: функция нигде не вызывается, поэтому ничего и не выводится.

Comment: во-вторых, банальная опечатка в условии `for`: `i > radioButtArray.length` - оно сразу false, потому в цикл даже не заходит

Comment: в-третьих, нет функции `.foreach()`, есть [функция `.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getRadioEl() {
    var radioButtСollection = document.getElementsByClassName("markNews"); 
    [].forEach.call(radioButtСollection, function( el ) {
        if (el.checked === false){
            console.log('false for ', el);
        }else{
            console.log('true for ', el);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getRadioEl() {
  var radioButtСollection = document.getElementsByClassName("markNews");
  // получаю html коллекцию, в ней 18 элементов
  var radioButtArray = Array.from(radioButtСollection);
  //привожу коллекцию  к массиву
  for (var i = 0; i < radioButtArray.length; i++) {
    if (radioButtArray[i].checked === false) {
      console.log('false for ' + radioButtArray[i]);
    } else {
      console.log('true for ' + radioButtArray[i]);
    }
  }
}

getRadioEl();
```

```css
.ThisDay-default-index {
  position: relative;
}

.control-group .group-header:not(:nth-child(1)) {
  display: none;
}

.horizontal-scroll-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.control-group {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  max-width: 285px;
  max-height: 345px;
  min-height: 345px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
}

.thisday-container {
  width: 55%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.control {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.control input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.control__indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 4px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
}

.control-views-count {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font: normal normal normal 13px/1 FontAwesome;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #695454;
}

.control-views-count:before {
  margin: 4px;
}

.thisday-butt,
.thisday-btn {
  float: right;
}

.thisday-time {
  display: flex;
}

.thisday-content {
  clear: both;
}

.control-group .group-header:not(:nth-child(1)) h3 {
  display: none !important;
}

.control-button__container {
  text-align: center;
}

.thisday-list__button {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.group-header {
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.thisday-time #userdate {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

.bs-native-danger {
  color: #a94442;
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #ebccd1;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.thisday-form-butt {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.markNews {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

.markNews+.markNews_label__custom {
  background: #dad7d7;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.markNews:checked+.markNews_label__custom::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  background-color: #58b790;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.markNews_label__custom:hover {
  background: #cfe330;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.markNews-label {
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.label-checked {
  background-color: #72f1638f;
}

.control-group__label:not(.label-checked):hover,
.control-group__label:not(.label-checked):focus {
  background-color: #9dd9f68f;
}
```

```html
<div class="thisday-container">
  <span>Вы можете выбрать еще <strong id="countRadioButt"></strong> новостей</span>
  <div class="horizontal-scroll-wrapper">
    <div class="control-group">
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612539" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612539" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612539" 
    class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">13556                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612210" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612210" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612210" 
   class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">11376                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label label-checked">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612573" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612573" checked="checked" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612573" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">7523                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612378" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612378" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612378" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст</span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">7340                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612349" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612349" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612349" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">7068                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612405" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612405" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612405" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">5811                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612577" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612577" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612577" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">4354                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612478" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612478" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612478" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст</span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">4309                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612586" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612586" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612586" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">3887                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612443" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612443" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612443" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст</span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">3641                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612550" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612550" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612550" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст</span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">3404                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612479" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612479" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612479" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">3241                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612421" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612421" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612421" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">3196                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612466" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612466" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612466" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст</span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">3081                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-612380" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 612380" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-612380" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">2901                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>

    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <h3 class="group-header">2016</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-523521" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2016][]" value=" 523521" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-523521" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текстм </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">3146                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2016</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label ">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-523515" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2016][]" value=" 523515" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-523515" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">2766                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>


      <h3 class="group-header">2016</h3>
      <label class="control-group__label label-checked">
                                <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-523477" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2016][]" value=" 523477" checked="checked" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
                                <label for="mark-radio-523477" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
      <span class="markNews-label">Текст </span>
      <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">1825                            </i>
      </label>
      <div class=""></div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```